# Scraping Twitter content using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, twitter, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I make a list from twitter content that I have scraped? I have scraped the content from tweets, now I want to make a list in order to manipulate it. How do I this?

I am using python 3.6

[here is my code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzH7u.png)

**here is what prints:**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Add your complete code and output in the question. Don't post links to images.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = soup.get_text(separator=' ') #any separator if you want to use one
list = []
list.append(text)
```

If you want to split the twits you will need regex.

Comment: How would I separate a tweet's content by stock ticker symbol using Regex? ei.-- $PLUG is up 5% today --

Comment: Plz be more specific, you want to split from $ till where . You will need to show me a good portion of your twits form.